# Does Django ManyToMany field's set() operation clear existing relations?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views, django-orm

Is there any difference between below 2 cases in Django ORM operation? Will there be any performance gains etc?

```
obj.manytomanyfield.clear()
obj.manytomanyfield.add(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and

```
obj.manytomanyfield.set([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the doc, [**`set()`**-Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set)

> This method accepts a `clear` argument to control how to perform the
> operation. If `False` (the default), the elements missing from the new
> set are removed using [`remove()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove) and only the new ones are added. If
> `clear=True`, the [`clear()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear) method is called instead and the whole set is
> added at once.

Which means,

```
obj.manytomanyfield.clear()
obj.manytomanyfield.add(1,2,3,4,5)
```

is ***equal to***

```
obj.manytomanyfield.set([1,2,3,4,5], clear=True)
```

Comment: So, ultimately the obj will have only (1,2,3,4,5) relations. Correct?

Comment: @Jarvis I am pretty sure: yes. Regarding performance, I am also interested because I am not sure what the purpose of the `clear` argument really is (maybe race conditions because that is mentioned in the docs).